# VS 2017 Modeling project

Tags: visual-studio-2017, uml, class-diagram, sequence-diagram

I have a modeling project for my application. it created before using VS 2013. after upgrading to VS 2017 i cannot view the content of any file with  the following extensions **.classdiagram**, **.sequencediagram**.

when i click any file with any of the above extensions i can only view XML tags.

Note: I installed ModelProject and class designer features for VS 2017